# Adding a record into an association table using Breezejs

Tags: breeze

**Background Info**

So I am using Breezejs and Knockout with EF5 and the Breeze MVC api controller on the backend. One of my tables in my data base is an association table, 3 columns - an id and two foreign keys(we'll call them fkey1 and fkey2 with table1 and table2). In my application, I need to add a record to this association table. Breeze knows about the relationships that this table has.

**Situation**

Breeze js makes a new record for me, then I find out the records I need to associate with it. Do I need to add in the id of the table1 entity into the fkey1 observable and the table2 entity id into the fkey2 observable AND add the whole entities into their respective relationship properties AND add push this new entity object into the table1 and table2 entities association property? Or does adding the id's into the new object automatically add those objects into the relationship properties (maybe those objects are subscribed to the fkey1 and fkey2 properties? - this is what I'm guessing happens in the background of breeze, a shot in the dark though I have no idea).

Creating new entities with Breeze is super easy and I love it, but I'm a little confused when it comes to creating new entities that have a lot of relationships.

Let me if you need a better description of my situation, it's kind of a tough thing to explain. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing that you set the "foreign key" properties appropriately when creating and attaching entities, Breeze will automatically update all of the associated relationships, i.e. navigation properties on this and any related entities.  You should never need to manually perform any fixup.

Similarly, if you do the reverse and assign an entity to a scalar navigation property then Breeze will automatically update the foreign key(s).  For a collection navigation property, if you push a value into the collection then Breeze will automatically update the foreign key of the entity being pushed.

Hope this helps, but maybe I'm missing the question...

Comment: Can you create a new entity, then add the foreign key value after?

Comment: Yes, and it will update correctly. You can set either the fk or the navigation property and get the same result. Note that none of this occurs until the entities are attached to an entityManager. The act of updating a nav property will automatically bring entities into the entityManager if either side is already attached, but this can't be done for fk's.  So make sure both sides of any relation where you want to update fk's are already attached.